# How do I highlight when there is a run of 2 candles but less than 4?

Tags: pine-script

Hi this is my first code and am just going round and round trying to find out how to do it.
What I'm trying to achieve is an overlay which colours when there is a run of 2 candles the same but only colouring when the second candle has less volume than the first. there are other things which I would also like to add to this in the future but I am just really stuck on this part currently. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
this is what I have so far

```
//@version=4
study(title="Highlight candles", overlay=true)
///////////////////////Candles//////////////////////////////////////////////
greenCandle = (close > open)
redCandle = (close < open)

twoGreenCandles = greenCandle[1] and greenCandle
twoRedCandles = redCandle[1] and redCandle

////////////VOL////////////////////////
volumecng = volume[1] > volume

///////////////////candle and vol true////////////////
greenv2 = twogreencandles=true and volumecng =true

/////////////////////////Background////////////////////////////////////////////////
bgcolor(color=greenv2 ? color.lime : na)
bgcolor(color=twoRedCandles ? color.fuchsia : na)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using = twice in one row will cause an error as = is used to define a variable. == can be used to check if something is equal to another value in a statement.

eg.

x = close == close[1]

would only return true if close values were equal 2 bars in a row. However, because twoGreenCandles and volumecng are Booleans, we can simply put the 2 together with the use of "and".

```
//@version=4
study(title="Highlight candles", overlay=true)
///////////////////////Candles//////////////////////////////////////////////
greenCandle = (close > open)
redCandle   = (close < open)

twoGreenCandles = greenCandle[1] and greenCandle
twoRedCandles   = redCandle[1]   and redCandle

////////////VOL////////////////////////
volumecng = volume[1] > volume

///////////////////candle and vol true////////////////
greenv2 = twoGreenCandles and volumecng 
redv2   = twoRedCandles   and volumecng 

/////////////////////////Background////////////////////////////////////////////////
bgcolor(color=greenv2 ? color.lime    : na)
bgcolor(color=redv2   ? color.fuchsia : na)
```

note: an alternative to the background color here is a bar color change. For this swap out bgcolor() with barcolor() to change the color of the candles instead

Cheers!

Comment: Brilliant, thankyou so much, and for the information. Im very new to pine so thankyou for the education also. real big help,

Comment: No problem Blake! You take care!